# Passing service data to controller ng

Tags: angularjs, service, controllers

When I get the data from the service using getAllGenres everything works fine, but when I try to pass the parameter vm.id the data is of type undefined. Please help. P.S. from an Angular new comer

genresService:

```
angular.module('movies.services', [])
.factory('genresService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    function callback () {
        // TODO: Implement callback function
    }

    function getAllGenres (callback) {
        var url = '/api/genres';

        $http.get(url)
            .success(function  (data) {
                callback(data);
            })
            .error(function  (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    function getGenreById (id) {
        var url = '/api/genres/' + id;
        console.log(id);

        $http.get(url)
            .success(function  (data) {
                callback(data);
            })
            .error(function  (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    return {
        getAllGenres: getAllGenres,
        getGenreById: getGenreById
    };
}]);
```

GenresController:

```
.controller('GenresController', ['$scope', 'genresService', 
            function ($scope, genresService) {
    var vm = this;

    genresService.getAllGenres(function (data) {
        vm.genres = data;
    });
}])
```

GenresDetailsController:

```
.controller('GenreDetailsController', ['$routeParams', 'genresService', 
        function ($routeParams, genresService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.id = $routeParams.id;

    genresService.getGenreById(vm.id, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
}]);
```

Comment: Please do not bother with my stupidity, I fixed the error :D

Comment: You can delete the question then =)